# Forge - export RFI data to PDF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have a requirement to export RFI data as a PDF file using Forge API (similar to how export works on the sites RFI page).
I was referring to this [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/rfis-v2-rfis-GET/), and there is no API documented to directly download RFI as a PDF file.

What's the best way to achieve this? one way is to create the PDF on the client side using data retrieved from /rfis endpoint?
Is there any other better way to do this?

@autodesk: Exposing the API used to download RFI as a PDF, would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

RFI API does not provide the ability to export to PDF. To produce a pdf file, you will have to use a third-party library such as jsPDF.

You can try using a clash pdf export as a guide: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashpdfexport

Since you’re seeking to export your file, one solution you should consider is using the Data Connector API. It will output the data from BIM360/ACC database directly. This makes it very suitable for large data export, then using single endpoints of RFI to dump page by page.

Data Connector exports to CSV, which means you must convert it to PDF. In this case you still must use a 3rd party tool that can convert CSV to PDF.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-data-connector-api-available-public-beta